# How to set child to 100% width of context when parent has a fixed width in table?

Tags: html, css

I have `<table>` with expandable content. What I want to achieve is for the table in the expanded content to take up 100% of the width of the parent table. Is that possible?

The purpose of displaying the expanded content as a part of the cell is for the tabbing to be displayed in the correct order.

Here is a [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-merkle-hfvbq?file=/src/styles.css) to reproduce the table.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Most likely you will have to create another `tr` after this that will be shown on button click. In your current html this will not be possible.
I mean it is achievable but with absolute positioning that will be a pain to implement.

try something like this

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td> <button>Button that will trigger showOnClick-1 to show</button> </td>
    <td>sth</td>
    <td>sth</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="showOnClick-1">
    <td colspan="3">asd</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

***EDIT***

---

You can create custom element that will work like table but will be more, let's say customizable.
In this example i have used `grid` that allows me to place them shape that you need and will maintain tabbing order.

```css
.custom-table {
    max-width: 500px;
}

.item {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr;
}

.item-cell {
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
}

.full-w {
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-column-end: 4;
}

.order-1 {order: 1;}
.order-2 {order: 2;}
.order-3 {order: 3;}
.order-4 {order: 4;}
```

```html
<div class="custom-table">
    <div class="item">
        <div class="item-cell order-1">
            <button>1</button>
        </div>
        <div class="item-cell order-2">sth</div>
        <div class="item-cell order-4 full-w">
            <button>2</button>
        </div>
        <div class="item-cell order-3">
            <button>3</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. However, If I create another `<tr>` as the expandable content, the tabbing would go from "more info", "another tabbable button" and then to "hide info". Which is not the correct order. The UU is more important in this matter, so this is not the solution fo me.

Comment: I have updated my answer with another simple example that will use `grid` instead of table. This way it will preserve tabbing order. Hope it helps.